# Purchasing a Used Car - Advice

Tags: engine, vw, used

I'm looking into purchasing my first vehicle. I have a friend who's really into buying/selling VW's and he has a Jetta from the early 2000's with 240 000 km on it that he insists is  a great deal and says I should buy. I have a lot of reservations about a car with that many km on it, especially since I live in Canada and it would have been driven through the winter. I'm a student, and I won't be working full time again until next summer, so I can't afford a major repair within the next year.

Do VW's really have that superior of engines that it still has lots of life after 240 000 km?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: In order to provide an informed response, we would need to know specifically which engine and transmission are in the Jetta you are considering. A specific model year would be helpful as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You've asked a question that is primarily opinion-based and, as such, won't have a definitive answer.  Our "chat" site is a much better place to have this sort of open-ended discussion.  Please see our "about" page for more guidance on question asking & answering: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researching on the web it looks like this car may have a bad track record in general but can't say for sure about the particular one you are interested in.

If you are looking to save money and get on with your life reliably, there may be something better.

See [consumer reviews](http://www.edmunds.com/volkswagen/jetta/2002/consumer-reviews.html).

[This](http://autos.msn.com/research/vip/Reliability.aspx?year=2000&make=Volkswagen&model=Jetta) shows the engines have actually been a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never buy used goods from friends. Ever. The VW Jetta is probably one of the better high-mileage cars you can buy but I've never seen one with more kilometers than that on the road. If it was mostly driven on the highway at cruising speeds and there are no weird sounds and creaks, it might be worth considering, but I won't ever touch a second-hand car with more than 160 000km on the clock. Anything more and you have to start replacing expensive parts like steering racks, wiring looms, alternators, etc.